# Getting rid of unwanted subdir suffix in URL with .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a URL `https://example.com/portfolio/portfolio/page/2/` which I need to redirect to `https://example.com/contact/`

My attempts are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/portfolio/portfolio/page/2/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?/page/2/(.*)$ /contact/$1 [R,L]
```

OR

```
Redirect 301 /portfolio/portfolio/page/2/ /contact/
```

Both fail and redirect to `https://example.com/contact/page/2/` instead of just `https://example.com/contact/`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why did you use `?` after `^/`? Are you trying to match any 0+ chars? Then replace `?` with `.*`

Comment: your second rule is right according to this fiddle http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=b5f46c13-1fed-57ac-b919-e8598c4bd986

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i changed to `RewriteRule ^/portfolio/portfolio/page/2/(.*)$ /contact/$1 [R,L]` Didn't work

Comment: @anubhava Didnt help :(

Comment: @fxlacroix that's pretty straightforward. Is there any particular reason why my webserver behaves like this? How can I debug this?

Comment: And what does "didn't work" actually mean?

Comment: did you try to restart it ? i know you don't have to normally but i don't know your server configuration

Comment: Your question is contradictory. Please clearly state what URL you want to 1. rewrite, 2. see in the browser and 3. want to be called internally.

Comment: @arkascha I want to redirect from this https://example.com/portfolio/portfolio/page/2/ to 2 this https://example.com/contact/ and the later should be also be called for internally

Comment: Sorry, but that sounds strange. I assume you mean the other way 'round? That a request to `/contact` should be rewritten to `/portfolio/portfolio/page/2` Or does the object `/contact` really exist locally?

Comment: @arkascha Pls excuse me if i was confusing, but you are getting this wrong  : this url `/portfolio/portfolio/page/2` should lead to `/contact` the later does not really exist, but is supplied by WordPress

Comment: Ok, fine. And is there anything trailing behind the `/portfolio/portfolio/page/2` that should be preserved, since in the examples some attempt to capture such token is shown? So something like `/portfolio/portfolio/page/2/foo` which should be rewritten to `contact/foo`?

Comment: @arkascha There should be nothing trailing after 'https://example.com/contact/' This is all that must be visible.

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer with a straight forward implementation of what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the additional information you gave in the comments to the question this is the simple rewriting rule you want:

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewrite /?portfolio/portfolio/page/2/?$ /contact [END]
```

In case you want to change the URL visible in the browser, then you need to implement an external redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewrite /?portfolio/portfolio/page/2/?$ /contact [R=301]
```

In case this results in an internal server error (http status 500) then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. Try using the `[L]` flag instead of the `[END]` then. You will see a corresponding entry in your http servers error log file in that case.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: In my case I indeed don't have any other way to influence webserver rather than .htaccess. I solved the issue. I should have posted my whole htaccess file. The thing was that somewhere before the string `Redirect 301 /portfolio/portfolio/page/2/ https://example.com/contact/ ` I had `Redirect 301 /portfolio/portfolio/ /contact/` And the later resulted in gibberish i had. All i had to do to fix it is to place `Redirect 301 /portfolio/portfolio/page/2/ https://example.com/contact/` ABOVE `Redirect 301 /portfolio/portfolio/ /contact/`. Sorry for trouble. A valuable lesson learnt today...

Comment: Ah, sure. One more case that clearly demonstrates that one should post as much detail as possible right along with the question. Take care handling the trailing slashes (`/`) correctly, though...